# Azure B2C Access Token NULL Spring OAuth 2.0

Tags: spring, azure, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get a custom web application to work with Azure B2C OAuth and the Spring OAuth2.0 framework.

The authentication leg comes back fine and I receive a JWT token. When the request for a token occurs afterwards I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access token provider returned a null access token, which is illegal according to the contract.
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:223) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
...
```

From some debugging of the spring code I can see the token is expected to be called `access_token` as seen in the `OAuth2AccessToken` class. From looking at the B2C tutorials their token is called `token_id`. Furthermore the applications.yml config I have for my spring application has a field called tokenName. Surely this should be used to pick up the token name field instead of the hardcoded static variable as above.

Am I missing something and is there a solution to my problem. Can I override the token name field used by the spring OAuth framework?

Comment: I've gotten to the point where I'm getting this same error. I created a link to take the user to the default azure login screen, and after logging in it redirects back to my webapp. And then I get that same error as you.

Comment: Yeah I think it is not compatible with spring yet. It is unfortunate that Azure have deviated from the "normal" token name. I have not been able to solve this as of yet and will wait for it to become more stable.

Comment: I did a little digging and debugging into the Spring OAuth classes, and found that it is not adding the "scope" values to the request. According to the B2C documentation, at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc/, this is required. I put a LineBreak/debug in OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java(line: 137) and you will see that the form does not contain "scope" when requesting a token.

Comment: Just to clarify, that was for the token request.

Comment: If you are interested, I created a public github project with what I have configured so far. Be sure to add your own values for customer, clientId, and clientSecret in "application.yml". https://github.com/Pytry/azure-b2c-oauth2.git

Comment: You can configure a scope variable in the .yml file. Set it as `scope: openid`. I am able to get a valid token back but it cannot be unpacked properly even with the tokenName field set in the .yml file.

Comment: I've made some more changes. I've been able to get everything to work, right up until the content verification stage. Check out https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc/ And look at the "Token Verification" section. There is a ".wellknown" endpoint where you need to download an RSA key based on your policy name. Use that to create an RSASigner and RsaVerifier. It gets updated every 12 hours or so. A scheduled task will need to be created to see if it has changed and then reload the security context when it does.

Comment: Here's the wellknown endpoint where you get the RSA key:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=your_policy_name_goes_here

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as the answer.

I started with the Spring tutorial, and made some modifications to it. For a working example, see the public github repo: https://github.com/Pytry/azure-b2c-oauth2.git

To properly parse the token received you will need:

- A custom implementation of an AccessToken that will parse the JWT, pulling and setting variables as required by spring security. I extended DefaultOAuth2AccessToken and added this parsing to a private method called by the constructor.
- If you are going to verify the RSA signature using the public keys, you will need a custom JWT object so you can access the header information. I chose to extend springs JWT, and add some parsing on creation to access the header. It may also be useful to have some custom Pojos for parsing the returned meta data and rsakey information into.
- An extension of the JwtAccessTokenConverter, with an overridden "decode" method. Azure does not give a "user_name" nor a "client_id" in the returned id_token, so you need to add those. I also included some logic in the super class that I found suefull (such as converting strings to int/long when appropriate).
- A custom UserDetailsManger to override the default in memory one. This can either retrioeve user information from the GraphAPI, or it can load it from your user repository. I actually did not create either of these, and instead used the default in memory service, but injected it into the token converter; then whenever a user was properly authenticated, I would add them to the managers store, or update them if they already existed.

There are a few things I have not done yet.

- RSA verification is not being done. Any help on this is appreciated.